# How can I display a svg in prawn without saving a .svg file before?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, svg, io, prawn

For this moment, I generate a svg file and then I read it and I display it in my pdf:

```
 qr = Barby::QrCode.new('test')
 outputter = Barby::CairoOutputter.new(qr).to_svg
 File.open('myfile.svg', 'wb'){|f| f.write outputter }
 pdf.svg IO.read('myfile.svg'), width: 50, height: 50
```

My question is: how can I display my svg without saving a .svg file before. I know there is a css property that allow that but I can't use css with prawn... 
Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of writing `outputter` to a file, have you tried using it as the parameter to `pdf.svg`?

Comment: Good idea, it works like that: pdf.svg outputter, width: 50, height: 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working like that:

```
pdf.svg outputter, width: 50, height: 50
```

thanks @Mark Thomas